How do I use Make to generate an arbitrary hierarchy that mirrors another
I have a directory named markdown that contains .md files and further subdirectories. I want to generate a corresponding html file for each md file.
This makefile works, but it requires a separate build directory:
SOURCES = $(shell find ./markdown -name "*.md")
HTML = $(patsubst ./markdown/%.md,./build/%.html,$(SOURCES))

all: $(HTML)

build/%.html: markdown/%.md
    @echo -e "Convert markdown file [$<] to html [$@]."


I just want to build in the markdown directory's parent, which is the root of the project, so I want:
./index.html
./foo/bar/hum/another.html
./markdown/index.md
./markdown/foo/bar/hum/another.md

I would expect to be able to just remove the two "build/" occurrences, so the changed lines would read:
HTML = $(patsubst ./markdown/%.md,./%.html,$(SOURCES))

and
%.html: markdown/%.md

This works with a top-level file (./markdown/index.md) but fails with anything else (e.g. ./markdown/foo/bar/hum/another.md). Why so?

I don't know if you were just careless with the question, but note that the pattern ./markdown/%.md does not match the string markdown/foo/bar/hum/another.md.  The ./ has to match as well.

@MadScientist Sorry, do you mean the patsubst? As far as I can tell, that's working as expected; SOURCES is ./markdown/index.md ./markdown/foo/bar/hum/another.md and HTML is ./index.html ./foo/bar/hum/another.html

In your comment (last paragraph) you omitted the ./ from the example strings.  That's why I mentioned it and asked if it was just carelessness in the details of the question, or reflected a real string that would not work correctly.

@MadScientist OK, i've edited those for clarity

I believe your problem is related to this behavior for pattern rule matching:

When the target pattern does not contain a slash (and it usually does not), directory names in the file names are removed from the file name before it is compared with the target prefix and suffix. After the comparison of the file name to the target pattern, the directory names, along with the slash that ends them, are added on to the prerequisite file names generated from the pattern rule’s prerequisite patterns and the file name.

You can either modify your pattern rule so the target contains a '/', or you can use static pattern rules:
$(HTML) : %.html: markdown/%.md
        ...


Fantastic — that static pattern rule did the trick, thank you so much! I'm curious as to how I would use the other approach (./%.html: ./markdown/%.md doesn't work) but I'll focus on the version that does work for now.

Unfortunately ./ is handled specially by make, so that it doesn't treat ./foo and foo as different targets.  You could use something like $(CURDIR)/%.html : $(CURDIR)/markdown/%.md and it should work but I didn't test it.
